# How to set a header in Puppeteer and access it using Angular in the newly opened browser?

Tags: node.js, angular, http, header, puppeteer

I try to open a browser and pass a costume header using Puppeteer in the Node.js server:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({"headless": false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
  'id':id});
await page.goto('http://localhost:4200/PDF');
const pdf = await page.pdf(options);
```

Now I want to use this 'id' header in the opened browser to retrieve data from a database, based on that ID.
An interceptor I used made it possible to access the header only on the page which triggers the Puppeteer
How can I access it in the http://localhost:4200/PDF too?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want a custom header to be available to every opened pages ? In your code, the problem is that you're setting a custom header only for the first opened page. 
If you want it to be available browser-wide, you need to set a listener for every opened target ('targetcreated' event) and set the custom header each time it is called.

Comment: No, I want to use it only in the first opened page, but i don't know how to do it. I know how to intercept outgoing requests but not incoming, any other way to access that header?

Comment: What do you mean by "An interceptor I used made it possible to access the header only on the page which triggers the Puppeteer" ? Can you provide the code for interceptor ? What is the "page which triggers the Puppeteer" ?